# Postgis 2.0 - How to get a Point from given LinestringM and a measure?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, linear-referencing

If I have a cable route linear referenced and stored in a LinestringM with M value is the length (in meters) from the start of the route - for example:

```
LINESTRING M (0 0 0, 10 0 20, 12 0 40, 20 0 50, 21 0 70)
```

Now I know the cable route is broken at *45 meters from start point*, that would be in the middle of two points `(12 0 40)` and `(20 0 50)` (see the M value). With Postgis, how can I get the broken point coordinate - which should be `POINT (16 0)` in this case?

Comment: Use http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html based on the M values at the start and end? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this design - why didn't you just use the length of the linestring as the length value?

Comment: @BradHards: for cable routes, there will be slack loops (excess cable coiled for future use) which can not be drawn accurately in the linestring, so I have to store cable sheath length in M value and calculate from it.

Comment: So are those slack loops only present on the start/end node or can they be in between if there are more points in the linestring? If this is the catch then example should include that.

Comment: @JakubKania: Those slack loops can be any where on the cable route, most notably when the cable must cross big streets, there will be larger chance that the cable will be broken by oversized trucks. And when that happens, you will have excess cable to use right away.

Comment: @JakubKania: I updated the example to clarify my idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function needed is [ST_LocateAlong](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_LocateAlong.html)

From the manual page example, I thought it just works with measures that already exists in the LinestringM but after testing, this works:

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT((ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom)
    FROM
    (SELECT ST_LocateAlong(
            ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRINGM (0 0 0, 10 0 20, 12 0 40, 20 0 50, 21 0 70)'), 45) As the_geom) As foo;
```

Returns:

```
"POINTM(16 0 45)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example working for a line with only two points in it. If you have more than 2 points in your line, you will have to loop through the points and sum the Z value.

Anyway, You can use `ST_Line_Interpolate_Point` to get the point from a fraction of the total distance. Here you can calculate `10 / the_Z_dimension_of_the_end_point`:

```
SELECT 
  ST_AsText(
    ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(
      geom,
      (10 / ST_Z(ST_EndPoint(geom)))
    )
  )
FROM
  (SELECT ST_LineFromText('LINESTRING(0 0 0, 10 0 20)') as geom) as yourline
```

This will give you:

```
"POINT Z (5 0 10)"
```

PS: Note that in 2.1 the function seems to have been renamed ST_LineInterpolatePoint

Comment: I updated the question. Can you show me how to do in this case? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a Z value, those are 2d points with an extra information as the third value.

Comment: That's right, ST_LocateAlong is the way to go.